# im trying to retrieve blob ( image ) from mysql db using php web servive for android app but the blob column still getting null

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am trying to retrieve blob ( image ) from mysql db using php web servive  for android app but the blob column still getting null
 the insert code works fine but retrieve code return null even if the blob column is not empty 
how can i fix this ?

```
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM core") or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // looping through all results
            $response["articles"] = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                // temp user array
                $product = array();
                $product["AID"] = $row["ID"];
                $product["ATitle"] = $row["title"];
                $product["ADate"] = $row["date"];   
                $product["AImage"]  = base64_encode($row["data"]);
               // $product["AImage"] =mysql_real_escape_string($b64img);
                $product["AArticle"] = $row["article"];

                // push single product into final response array
                array_push($response["articles"], $product);
            }
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;


        }
        `

  //  insert part 
        ` 
            $base= $_POST['image'];
            $buffer = base64_decode($base);
            $buffer = mysql_real_escape_string($buffer);
            $sql ="INSERT INTO `core`(`title`,`date`,`article`,`image`)VALUES ('$title','$date','$article','$buffer')";`
```

Comment: You need to access the image as $_FILES['image']['tmp_name].

Comment: @james: that'd only be true if an actual upload was performed. the image could be something like a b64 string serialized from a `<canvas>`

Answer (score 0):

easy ...

This is incorrect ...

`$product["AImage"]  = base64_encode($row["data"]);`

This is correct ...

`$product["AImage"]  = base64_encode($row["image"]);`

You were selecting `data` when it should be `image`

Comment: i fix it but its still getting null  .